# iPhone Address Book: How to get a list of only contacts with phone numbers?

Tags: iphone, filter, contacts, addressbook

I'd like to get a list of all ABContacts that have a phone number and only those contacts. Any contacts with just an email I do not want to show.

Android has a field called HAS_PHNONE_NUMBER you can query on but I'm not seeing anything like that for iPhone.

For example:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
//How do I filter people into an array of contacts that all have a phone number?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this code snippet

```
CFIndex numberOfPeople = CFArrayGetCount(_allPeople);
for (int i=0;i < numberOfPeople;++i) { 
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(_allPeople, i);
    ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    int phoneNumbersCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones);
    if (phoneNumbersCount>0)
    {
       // save this contact, it has phone number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way or help like this in iOS, you have to parse your Array and if the people you are parsing have a phone number or a list of phones number not empty you add it to your final Array.

Comment: Thanks. What about using NSPredicate? Would something like [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phonenumbers contains[cd] %@", number]; work?

Comment: ABAddressBook objects are not NSEntityDescription objects, so I don't think that you can perform request on them.