# How to get iPhone contacts in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, contacts, abaddressbook

I want to get all the iPhone contacts in my iphone application.Is it possible?If so how?Anybody please help me.

Comment: Hii... If my ans is correct then u can mark it as a correct ans.

Comment: Check this it may help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174889/iphone-how-to-access-the-phone-contact-list-and-display-it-in-tableview

Answer (score 7):

Apple has a programming guide for the address book framework:

[Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Reference:

- http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/61920-losing-imagedata-contact-when-adding-array.html
- [ABAddressBook store values in NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781211/abaddressbook-store-values-in-nsdictionary)
- http://iappdevs.blog.co.in/tag/how-to-get-contact-details-from-iphone-address-book-to-iphone-sdk/
- [iPhone Address Book: How to get a list of only contacts with phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352938/iphone-address-book-how-to-get-a-list-of-only-contacts-with-phone-numbers)
- http://appleresearch.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-get-contacts-with-iphone-sdk.html
- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=449981

Comment: My requirement is to get the contact list in an array in the application.

Comment: Hello Priya, See my updated Ans. I have add new two links at start point in Reference section.

Comment: what are the required frameworks and how to add frameworks in xcode 4?

Comment: ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSMutableArray *retVal = [(NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab) autorelease];
    CFRelease(ab);
    NSLog(@"hhjfdfdsbdfdskj");
    NSLog(@"%@",retVal);
Is this is enough for getting contacts?

Comment: Its store the data in to NSDictionary. Can we talk on any other messenger more help?

Comment: This is an array ..right?The retVal array will contain contacts?I am not getting anything?Thats why i asked.