# Get iPhone address book contacts in iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone application.Within which I want to get all the iphone address book contacts in an array.

Is that possible?

Comment: This question was asked already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674875/how-to-get-iphone-contacts-in-iphone-application

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [ABAddressBook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

for( int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ ) {
  ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i );
  NSLog(@"inside loop");
}
```